# Layout issue - Having trouble getting a view to appear below a frame layout

Tags: android

I am working on an app which has a paid and a free version. Both versions display a map, which could either be Google Maps or an OSM derived map at the moment, and I handle switching between them by loading a different map fragment for each one. There are also two buttons that need to be displayed at all times. On Honeycomb and later, I can handle this by making these buttons actions in a split action bar, but for backwards compatibility reasons, I also use a frame layout to make these buttons appear on top of the map if the Android version is earlier than Honeycomb.

In the paid version, the map is to take up all the available screen space. The problem is, for the free version, I need to have an ad banner at the top, and an image linking to my company's website at the bottom, with the map fragment in between. I am currently using a TextView for each one as placeholders, and I can get the one at the top to appear, but never the one at the bottom.

Here is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MapScreen" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/advertisement"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Advertisement placeholder" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/map_screen_button_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00000000"

        android:paddingBottom="22dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_button_normal"
                android:onClick="callbackRequest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/menu_callback_request"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_button_emergency"
                android:onClick="emergencyCallbackRequest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/menu_emergency_request" 
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/company_banner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Company Banner Placeholder" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

In my MapScreen activity's onCreate() method, I also do the following if the version running is the free version:

```
    TextView advertisement = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.advertisement );
TextView companyBanner = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.company_banner );

advertisement.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
companyBanner.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
```

How can I change this layout file to get both TextView objects to appear, without ruining how the layout appears within the FrameLayout?

Comment: Why don't you make a seperate layout file for the free version? That way if you set the visibility of company_banner to visible in the xml it should work..

Comment: I have considered that, so I tried setting it to visible in this layout file, and it still didn't work.

Comment: for this kind of layouts it would be better if you create the layouts programmaticaly in java. that way you can give two layouts and manage it using conditions like free or paid etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout file for the free version.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/advertisement"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Advertisement placeholder"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/company_banner"
    android:layout_below="@id/advertisement" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_screen_button_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="22dp"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_button_normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/menu_callback_request"
            android:onClick="callbackRequest" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_button_emergency"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/menu_emergency_request" 
            android:onClick="emergencyCallbackRequest" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/company_banner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Company Banner Placeholder"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: This is good. I tried using RelativeLayout a long time ago, but always had trouble actually making things display properly. Now I understand better how it works.

And no, I didn't need to use a separate layout. I just took the basic layout you've given here, and kept the same logic in my java code and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you have set `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` on your FrameLayout. change this to `wrap_content` and try.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I think the problem with that is that being a map fragment, the content can be as big as it needs to be, and will take up any space available to it. I'm not very good at understanding how the layouts work, but I suspect the size needs to be controlled by the rest of the layout.